# Open Source Qt projects deal with database connections

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, open-source, database-connection

I have a Qt application which heavily uses MySql Database. Do you know any open source Qt project which uses MySql? I wonder how did they manage database connections?

Comment to Harald Scheirich's Answer:

1-)QSqlDatabase::isOpen() doesn't work properly. http://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-223

2-)Using QSqlDatabase::open() in order to check database connection when MySql connection is gone very time consuming in my case.

Comment: Akonadi for example is written in Qt (non-gui) and uses MySQL: http://pim.kde.org/akonadi/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Google codesearch to search for [QMYSQL](http://www.google.com/codesearch?as_q=QMYSQL&btnG=Search+Code&as_package=&as_lang=c%2B%2B&as_filename=&as_class=&as_function=&as_license=&as_case=yes).

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything wrong with QDatabase ? We have a fairly large (non opensource) app that uses MySql together with the Qt provided drivers and the QSql infrastructure. It works fine with very little surprises.